# Calculation in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

in a table there are some months like

```
A        Sales
--------------
Jan14    20
Feb14    12
Mar14    13
Apr14    10
May14    10
```

So I want something which shows the output of quarter

```
Qtr       Sales
---------------
QTR114    45
QTR214    20
```

Qtr114 = Jan14+feb14+mar14 same goes for qtr214

how to do it dynamically?

Comment: I would say easiest way is to create a table for the months that has the quarter in there and then join that with your data. If your months are actually dates then you could do calculation but date table is probably better even then.

Comment: I will add another column in table called QuarterID.So when Month is Jan then id=1 and so on.After this it is very simple and will help among lot of data also.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your data exactly how you provided us, then this works:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    A VARCHAR(10)
    , Sales INT
);

INSERT INTO @Test
    (A, Sales)
VALUES
      ('Jan14', 20)
    , ('Feb14', 12)
    , ('Mar14', 13)
    , ('Apr14', 10)
    , ('May14', 10)
    , ('Jun14', 15)
    , ('Jul14', 80)
    , ('Dec14', 15)
    , ('Jan15', 15);

SELECT 'QTR' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), Q.Quarter) + (RIGHT(Y.Year, 2)) AS Qtr , SUM(Sales) AS Total
FROM @Test AS T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, STUFF(T.A, 4, 0, ' 20'))) AS Y(Year)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, STUFF(T.A, 4, 0, ' 20'))) AS Q(Quarter)
GROUP BY Y.Year, Q.Quarter
ORDER BY Y.Year, Q.Quarter
```

I had to format your date into right format to do grouping. CROSS APPLY is just to make code more readable.